# Plotly choropleth not working as expected

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to understand why no data is showing up on a plotly choropleth map

The full code is in [this kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/andrewstaroscik/plotly-express-choropleth-not-working-as-expected?scriptVersionId=126678658)

I am trying to graph some summary data by state using a choropleth map with Plotly Express. I've recreated the problem in the notebook above using county-level population data from the US Census Bureau.

The raw data has multiple entries per state, which I am using groupby to summarize by state.

```py
 df = df_raw.groupby('State')['Population'].agg(['count','sum','mean','median','max','min']).reset_index()
```

Then graphing it with plotly

```py
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    locations='State',
    color = 'sum',  
    locationmode='USA-states',
    scope='usa'
)
fig.show()
```

The chart renders and the scale to the right is scaled properly, but there is no color fill in the state shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces in names of states:

```py
df['State'] = df['State'].str.strip()
```

Hope that helps!